# Collaborative Coded UI tests

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, coded-ui-tests

I have a question about Coded UI and how to best use it together with others. We are a team(of 3) who are testing a large web application(which is hard by itself) but we also want to make all the tests in one solution and share that solution through GIT(or TFS). What is the best way of doing this?

We have tried a few things already. We tried using the default UI map, but this creates a lot of merge conflicts and the UI map class becomes long and hard to understand.

We also tried using different UI maps for every page on the site. This seemed like a good idea since we all could test different parts of the website. The problem with this was that once you created one UI map and mapped the content of that page, you could not go back to mapping against that UI map again. So if we had mapped one page and then written a few tests and then some functionality was added, we could not go back to map this. If we created a new test and mapped through this test, this mapping was added to the default UI test. I think this method would work if we could just change which UI map the code would be added to for a new test.

Any reply would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To record and add new methods and controls into a UI Map other than the default, right-click on the UI Map's `.uitest` file in solution explorer and select the "**Edit with Coded UI test builder**" menu entry. By contrast, if you right-click in a method within the test sources and select the "**Generate code for Coded UI test**" menu entry then it will write to the default UI Map; creating it without warning if it does not exist. See also this Visual Studio user voice entry http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3378897-choosing-the-uimap-when-recording-tests

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you`ve read this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398056.aspx

In case of my app with similar issues we`ve got rid off UI Maps and hand code everything, wrap it in methods and make is as reusable as possible.